# Tesseract OCR specify number/location of characters

Tags: config, ocr, tesseract

I'm having trouble getting accurate OCR results using Tesseract.  I have a series of many small images with time, date, lat and lon text that I'm trying to have Tesseract read.  The images are cropped from videos, some with low quality.
The images from each group all have the same format (e.g. time: ## : ## : ##, see image below).
But, Tesseract is giving variable results.  For example, an image showing "14:10:08" is read as "142:" (one of the worst results from the data set).
I have trained Tesseract for these images, and that improved the results.

My main question is: is there a way to specify the number of characters Tesseract should read?  In this case, something like `tesseract time.png time -num_char 8`?  Or is there a way to specify the width of blobs/boxes Tesseract should implement looking at the picture?

I've experimented with configfiles (as explained [on this site](http://www.sk-spell.sk.cx/tesseract-ocr-parameters-in-302-version)), but there's a whole lot of settings and I don't understand many of the explanations (is "Max width of blobs to make rows" what I'm looking for? Didn't seem to help...).

Thanks for any suggestions.

[image]

Comment: If they all have the same format, font and location then a solution using shape/pattern matching would have a much better results.

Comment: Is shape/pattern matching different than training Tesseract?  They do all have the same format, font, and location (character spacing).